# Why does SBT find imports while compiling but not while building the project?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am working on a Scala sbt project and this is how the project structure looks like.

[image]

This is the content of build.sbt file:

```
name := "Blitzkreig"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.2"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.21"
```

The only jar I added externally is gsp.jar which can be seen in the project structure image above.
I added the jar as libraries -> `+` -> Java Module -> Path_Of_Jar_File.

[image]

When I completed the code, I didn't see any compilation errors with import statements. But when I build the project I see the same import statements giving error and all the errors are from gsp.jar file.

For example:
[image]

The package for which the import statement is giving an error is also present and it can be seen in the image below.

[image]

When I click on building the jar, I see the same import statement resulting the error as below.

```
[info] Executing in batch mode. For better performance use sbt's shell
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 26 Nov, 2020 4:33:10 PM
[info] Compiling 17 Scala sources to /Users/bobby/IdeaProjects/Blitzkreig/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[error] /Users/bobby/IdeaProjects/Blitzkreig/src/main/scala/com/tablecolumn/TGetTableColumn.scala:5:8: not found: object gudusoft
[error] import gudusoft.gsqlparser._
```

Is there any problem with the way I am importing the jar file into the project. Could anyone let me know what did I do wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You added JAR only in IntelliJ, sbt doesn't see it. So IntelliJ compiler might be able to compile code and doesn't show any errors, but sbt sees only missing packages.

If you want to avoid this kind of issues NEVER add libraries through IDE, always add them as either managed or unmanaged dependencies via your build tool (be it sbt, Maven, gradle or something else) and then refreshing your project in IDE (for each build system there is a dedicated option to resynchronize build).

It doesn't matter that you added "only one package" externally - if you added any package at all omitting build system you have a broken setup.

If you want to add unmanaged dependency (because e.g. it is not published on artifactory) add it to [`lib` directory](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Unmanaged+dependencies).

Comment: oh wow. I've been working on SBT projects since three years & I didn't care how to add an external jar as a dependency. I added the external jar as a dependency in build.sbt as: `unmanagedJars in Compile += file("/Users/bobby/Downloads/Software/jars/gsp.jar")` and the import errors are gone.

Comment: I got one question though. In other projects I worked on, when ever I faced `ClassNotFound Exception` for ex: a database driver class, I used to add the external jar as a I gave in the image from the question and it used to fix the issue. How is that different to the one I am facing now. This should permanently solve my doubt. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: A wild guess, but probably you never references the driver directly in your code, only in class-name-as-string runtime reflection, so everything compiled but broke after running outside of IDE.

Comment: Not for all of them. One of my database is Greenplum & I have a custom jar for it ergo no official dependency available. I never used to keep that particular jar in build.sbt as unmanaged jar file. The code used to compile and build properly. It also ran because I used to make a fat jar with all the jar files I wanted. I only had Greenplum jar as an external jar so the fat jar in the end is never huge i.e. <1MB in most of the cases. But I got your point now, will use it in the way you mentioned from next time.